# Python stub files good practices

Tags: python, python-3.x

When developing python packages – I think – is quite good practice to use type hints. To make things cleaner I have decided to use Python's `.pyi` stub files. Since my package contains some sub-packages, should I put stub declarations inside each sub-module (which to me seems the best option) or should I put them in the main `__init__.pyi` of the whole package, [as NumPy does](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/__init__.pyi)?